# cannot fix Uncaught TypeError: e.target is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

In ***ReactJS*** I have a `component` as per below which

```html
<AutoComplete
              style={{ width: 400, fontSize: "13px" }}       
              placeholder="Search for a user"
              options={this.getUserOptions()}
              filterOption={true}
              onSearch={this.handleUserSearch}
              onSelect={this.onSelect}
            />
```

I then call a function on search called `HandleUserSearch`:

```
handleUserSearch = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target
    //do  stuff here
  }
```

but getting a

> Uncaught TypeError: e.target is undefined error.

anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You can debug by adding `console.log(e)` in `handleUserSearch` method. Eventually, you'll know which value is being passed.

Comment: thanks, have already tried that, getting undefined

Comment: That means `onSearch` prop doesn't give you value you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no event passed to the onSearch function. It looks like ANTD for me so to this function **the value is passed directly to the argument**.

```js
handleUserSearch = (value) => {
    const myValue = value; // value is the search criteria string
    //do  stuff here
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Because you do it wrong. You don't access it like this: value.target. You cannot access the target anywhere in that function because event is not passed there.

Answer (score 0):

what you did is correct, but instead of de structuring, can you try the same with logging the param to the console.

In another way, you can try like

```
<AutoComplete
    style={{ width: 400, fontSize: "13px" }}       
    placeholder="Search for a user"
    options={this.getUserOptions()}
    filterOption={true}
    onSearch={(event) => this.handleUserSearch(event)}
    onSelect={this.onSelect}
/>
```

and receive it like

```
handleUserSearch = (event) => {
   console.log(event);
   //do  stuff here
}
```

Comment: thanks  but that didnt change the outcome - still getting  undefined error

Comment: dont use the event in code, just log the param to the console, and see what you are getting

Comment: ah ok, yep so the event appears to be passing the search criteria to the function, but still getting the undefined error... and yes its AntD

Comment: Then look at my answer. You can use a value from argument directly, you don't need to access it from event because there is no event passed to the function.